# Start a Foreground Service From a Quick Tile on Android (targetSdkVersion 34 and higher)

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-14

I am the developer of a simple Android app that records location movements on behalf of the user. One can start the recording from the main Activity as well as from a Quick Tile. The recording takes place in a Foreground Service that displays a notification.

I recently updated the dependencies to `targetSdkVersion 34`. Since then the recording service cannot be started from the app's Quick Tile anymore.

This is how I start the recording Foreground Service from a Quick Tile:

- the app registers a `TileService`
- the `TileService` listens for taps on the Quick Tile in `onClick()`
- the recording Foreground Service is started from within the `TileService` via `application.startForegroundService(intent)`

This setup used to work with `targetSdkVersion 33`.

On `targetSdkVersion 34` a tap on the Quick Tile causes a crash. The log shows:

`android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service org.y20k.trackbook/.TrackerService`

I looked at the [Android 14 features and changes list](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/summary) and specifically at [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). But I fail to see what changed between Android 13 and 14 that affects my case.

I considered the following solutions:

1. Start an `Activity` from the `TileService` that in turn starts the Foreground Service. This approach seems to be clunky.
2. Implement the recording functionality into the `TileService` and try to promote it to a Foreground Service and show the notification from within the `TileService`

What do you think? Can anyone come up with a better solution?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/299506164. Doing the activity may be the only reasonable workaround for now.

Comment: @Y20K do you mind sharing the `Activity` workaround you're using? I tried to recreate it based on your description but was unable to :/

Comment: @Myzel394 I did not yet implement the `Activity` workaround. I just considered it. But I think it will be a bad user experience. For me sticking with `targetSdkVersion 33` makes more sense for now.

Comment: An easy workaround can be implemented by creating a dialog and dimissing it after enabling the service. An app is considered as a foreground process when a dialog is displayed. The downside is that the notification panel will collapse.
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE && !serviceEnabled) {
            val dialog = Dialog(this)
            dialog.setOnShowListener {
                toggleService()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            showDialog(dialog)
        } else {
            toggleService()
        }
`

Comment: Google yet again has broken another usefull functionality - you can't start a foreground service without "on top over all apps" permission anymore, you can't use camera, mic, location in a foreground service which is started from TileService anymore. And there is no info about such changes between Android 13 and Android 14

Comment: @ThomasW. hon are you supposed to open any ui/dialog if you click on the tile when device is locked? users can use them form lock screen...

Comment: @user924 Calling `TileService.showDialog` when the device is locked will ask the user to unlock the device, which is not ideal. After unlocking, the dialog will show which promotes your app to a foreground state in which you can start a foreground service. Perhaps using an activity would be the better option. The docs contain useful information on this topic: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#isLocked()